# How can I/O priority of a process be increased?

Tags: .net, file-io, windows-vista

I want to increase the I/O priority of a process. Answers for both .NET and Windows Vista would be nice. processexplorer is ok as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The relevant information seems to be a bit scattered compared to the usual MS documentation. There is this white paper that discusses [I/O Prioritization in windows](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fa%2Ff%2F7%2Faf7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b%2FPriorityio.doc&ei=6s8jSem3NqGksQOL1c3uDg&usg=AFQjCNHvihuifDRqFplOHe7Z1NY0ufmnDw&sig2=lL48ZkwbbP9KnqXn562XaQ). This doc seems to have beta flags all over it but I guess it's probably mostly pretty accurate.

Two important things to note:

1. You can only reduce the priority of IO requests below normal.
2. The driver can ignore any such request and treat it as normal anyway.

The useful APIs for client applications are [SetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365539(VS.85).aspx):

```
FILE_IO_PRIORITY_HINT_INFO priorityHint;
priorityHint.PriorityHint = IoPriorityHintLow;
result = SetFileInformationByHandle( hFile,
                                     FileIoPriorityHintInfo,
                                     &priorityHint,
                                     sizeof(PriorityHint));
```

[SetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219(VS.85).aspx):

```
// reduce CPU, page and IO priority for the whole process
result = SetPriorityClass( GetCurrentProcess(),
                           PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);
// do stuff
result = SetPriorityClass( GetCurrentProcess(),
                           PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END);
```

[SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277(VS.85).aspx) which is similar:

```
// reduce CPU, page and IO priority for the current thread
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);
// do stuff
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END);
```

[SetFileBandwithReservation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365537(VS.85).aspx):

```
// reserve bandwidth of 200 bytes/sec
result = SetFileBandwidthReservation( hFile,
                                  1000,
                                  200,
                                  FALSE,
                                  &transferSize,
                                  &outstandingRequests );
```

For .Net do the usual stuff with P/Invoke.

Comment: (You can only reduce the priority of IO requests below normal.)
Now I undestand why processexplorer only has normal and low I/O priority. Thanx for nice answer ...

Answer (score 14):

It looks like the "real" way to set the IO priority of a process is using `NtSetInformationProcess` with the `ProcessIoPriority` information class. Unfortunately this API is undocumented, but you can see it in action by attaching a debugger to taskeng.exe and breaking in `ExeTask::GetYourPrioritiesStraight`.

I believe the `PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS` value for `ProcessIoPriority` is 33 (0x21), and the priority values are as follows:

```
Very Low: 0
Low: 1
Normal: 2
High: 3 or above?
```

The values above are a best-guess based on what I can tell from the debugger; the task scheduler seems to use a value of 1 for tasks with priority 7, and a value of 2 for tasks with priority 5 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427142/is-there-anyway-for-a-win2k8-scheduled-task-to-have-normal-priority-io) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383512(VS.85).aspx) for more on task scheduler priorities). Calling `SetPriorityClass` with `PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN` uses a value of 0.

I have unfortunately not found any public API that can be used for this, other than the `SetPriorityClass` method in @1800 INFORMATION's answer, which sets the priority to Very Low.

Edit: I've written a utility that can be used to query or set the IO prority of a process, [available here](http://blog.misterfoo.com/2010/07/process-priority-utility.html).

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to do this is to call **SetProcessPriorityClass** with **PROCESS_BACKGROUND_MODE_BEGIN** to initiate a background mode. This causes a Very Low (background) I/O priority and Idle CPU priority. When done, call SetProcessPriorityClass again, supplying **PROCESS_BACKGROUND_MODE_END**. The same can be done at the thread level via **SetThreadPriority** and THREAD_BACKGROUND_MODE_BEGIN/END.

If you want to directly set the I/O priority, independently of the CPU priority, you must use the NT native APIs. I documented it [here](http://www.bitsum.com/pl_io_priority.php), but did not include code examples as we all know they get ripped verbatim.

The API you want is the NT Native API **NtSetInformationProcess**. Using this API you can change the I/O priority. This API accepts a 'class' variable telling it what type of information about the process you want to change, that class variable must be set to ProcessIoPriority. You can then set the entire process's I/O priority in this manner.

Similarly, the I/O priority can be retrieved via **NtQueryInformationProcess**.

The bad news is that the priority levels are a bit limited. Critical is reserved for system paging operations. That leaves you with **Normal** and **Very Low** (Background). Low and High may or may not be implemented in newer editions of Windows. There seems to be partial support, at the very least.

If you have no experience with the NT Native APIs, the first thing to do is understand them. Once you do, you'll see it is as simple as a single API call.

Comment: The article you linked to claims that setting the priority class of a process affects its I/O priority. I can't find any Microsoft documentation stating this fact. Moreover, my testing reveals that this is simply not the case.

Setting the priority class to 'Idle' on a process appears to NOT change its I/O priority.

Comment: The way Microsoft ended up doing this is via SetProcessPriorityClass and/or SetThreadPriority, indicating a 'background mode'. This causes Windows to adjust both the CPU priority (to Idle) and I/O priority (to Background) at a process level, or thread level, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to align `FILE_IO_PRIORITY_HINT_INFO` structure properly when calling `SetFileInformationByHandle`.

Otherwise, you will get a `ERROR_NOACCESS` (error 998, 0x000003E6).

```
_declspec(align(8)) FILE_IO_PRIORITY_HINT_INFO priorityHint;
priorityHint.PriorityHint = IoPriorityHintLow;

BOOL ret = SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileIoPriorityHintInfo, &priorityHint, sizeof(FILE_IO_PRIORITY_HINT_INFO));
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for this - it can all be done via .NET without resorting to WinAPI ...

```
// Set the current process to run at 'High' Priority
System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
process.PriorityClass = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.High;

// Set the current thread to run at 'Highest' Priority
Thread thread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
```

I've tried the above setting the process priority in a WPF application and it works fine. Haven't needed to set thread priority.

EDIT: this above relates to CPU priority of a process, as opposed to I/O priority, however there may be some correlation / connection between a process's CPU priority and its I/O priority.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a .NET equivalent of SetFileInformationByHandle to change IO priority, however as pointed out by 1800 INFORMATION this API only lets you reduce the priority to below normal.

Comment: isn't this the CPU priority, not the IO priority?

Comment: @CodeInChaos yes you're right, although you'd imagine there would be some connection between a process's CPU priority and its I/O priority?

Comment: When asynchronous I/O is used, this does very little because the thread is just sitting idle waiting anyways.  The I/O priority is much more important.  If you really want to be fancy, do both.  I'm still trying to figure out why Windows software RAID doesn't lower the I/O priority when you are rebuilding.

Comment: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). The I/O is not performed by the CPU, but by the network card or other specialized hardware. Setting the priority of the thread has no effect when a thread is not used anyway for the bulk of the I/O operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want critical I/O priority on files your app is dealing with, I believe renaming the files to .mp3 will get you that! Windows does this for media files like .mp3, .mp4 etc
It can be observed with Process Hacker in the Disk tab, as soon as anything reads mp3's you'll see they are all in critical I/O. I haven't found any documentation about this, there might be a registry setting?

Edit: This was on Win 7, I just tried on Win 10 and it's not the same, I saw it go to high priority once but usually normal, but never critical. While writing this I tried a Win 7 VM and it didn't do it there either! I don't know why my main Win 7 does it lol wonder if some third party but what? anyone know?

Comment: Super interesting answer to an age old question :)

Comment: want even more interesting check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59800820/990618 if you put -4 it just might work!

Comment: was updating win 10 today and music was horrible, pausing constantly, want it to behave like win 7 but how? ah but even win 7 doesn't do it for .flac