# Console application running from ssh(cygwin) works 10 times slower

Tags: performance, ssh, console, cygwin

I have a Windows computer where SSH server is set up. When I run the application on that computer from desktop, it takes 30 seconds to execute. But when I run the same application from ssh session it runs 300 seconds. 
It's not a connection speed problem, since the I have LAN connection to that computer. This is not some X11 issue, since my application is console. My application does some disk input(about 100 megabytes), then some CPU processing is involved, and in the end the processing results are saved into sqlite database (about 50 mb). It doesn't print almost any console messages while it's working.
I feel like it's something related to resource allocation for sshd process, because it's running as a Scheduler task. And I've noticed that application uses much less CPU when it's running in SSH session.
What can cause this slow down?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: [Is there any way for a win2k8 scheduled task to have normal priority IO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427142/is-there-any-way-for-a-win2k8-scheduled-task-to-have-normal-priority-io)
It was really about scheduler task priority. After setting the task priority to 4. The application works at the same speed as if running from desktop