# Windows Server 2012 R2 - High CPU / Memory Usage Causes Task Scheduler to Not Run?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a task that runs every minute on my Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.  This task gathers the system usage stats for my machine and sends it to Amazon CloudWatch.  I've noticed that during time periods of high CPU and memory usage, my stats aren't logged in Cloudwatch.  I've been able to rule out network interference as the cause of the problem by logging all the task scheduler calls to a text file on the local server drive.

Has anyone else encountered this problem before?  My CPU and memory usage are both over 80%, with the CPU usage sometimes hitting 100%.  If lack of CPU cycles is the root of the problem, is there anyway I can configure Task Scheduler to have priority over my other processes so as to ensure that the tasks always occur?

Comment: This seems to be more of a Server Fault question than a Stack Overflow question since it is not related to software development.  If you haven't posted it there I would recommend doing so.

Comment: I think you may be able to edit the associated XML file in C:\windows\Tasks or C:\windows\system32\tasks to change the priority, and then restart the task.  I would not change it to above normal unless you've proved it still fails with the highest "normal" setting.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all tasks created with Task Scheduler has a Windows resource utilization priority of 7 (below normal on a scale of 1 to 10).  You have to manually change this by exporting and re-importing the task to and from a XML file.

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427142/is-there-any-way-for-a-win2k8-scheduled-task-to-have-normal-priority-io), changed my task's utilization priority to 4, and saw a noticeable decrease of occurrences in which the task didn't run.