# Thread IO priorty settings

Tags: .net, multithreading

Can I set the IO priorty of managed thread? (C# code)

Once set, is the IO priority compared between threads within the same process, or cross processes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301290/how-can-i-o-priority-of-a-process-be-increased) on how to modify the I/O priority in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 (native APIs only, afai can see).  That might help you do what you want - exact requirements are not clear from the question.

The thread I referenced here points to [a white paper on this topic from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/priorityio.mspx).

Comment: Is there any Win2003 equivalent? S.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the [`Thread.Priority` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpriority.aspx).

This is an OS-level property which is compared among all active threads in every process.

Comment: Does that control the IO priorty as well? I was sure it controls the CPU

Comment: No, the Thread.Priority does not affect the I/O priority of a thread.  (It would tend to affect how quickly data is prepared for I/O operations which may have a similar effect depending on your application).