# How to set a I/O Priority of a Windows Process to High as Process Lasso does

Tags: windows, process, kernel32, nt

I know there are similar questions and tools [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301290/how-can-i-o-priority-of-a-process-be-increased)[(2)](https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7)[(3)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iopriority/) and many more.

Each of these resources in the web states that you need to use *Windows NT API* and with this it should be easy to change the priority. And it turns out, it is.

Using the function [NTSetInformationProcess](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FProcess%2FNtSetInformationProcess.html) from `ntdll.dll` you can change the I/O Priority.

As all of the cited and other resources state one can set I/O Priority at the maximal level of `Normal` which corresponds internally to the value `2` (`1` would mean `Low` and `0` means `Very Low`). And they are right. Specifying the parameter `ProcessInformation` with the values `0`, `1` and `2` is actually working.

Some of the resources mention the tool [Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/). This is a tool to change serveral process priorities including the I/O prio.
Here we have the option to set it to a value `High` which internally corresponds the value `3`. (I got this value from the function [NTQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess)).

Now one could think we can easily do this on our own and use the function [NTSetInformationProcess](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FProcess%2FNtSetInformationProcess.html) and specify the value `3` to the parameter `ProcessInformation`. But no, this will immediately set to value back to `2`.

Fortunately there is a [documentaion of Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/pl_io_priority.php) about the I/O Prio. The level `High` has a remark which says: "*Windows 7+ only (NT 6.1)*". I am on Windows 11 so this should mean the High Priority should be available. In this documentation [NTSetInformationProcess](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FProcess%2FNtSetInformationProcess.html) and [NTQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess) are mentioned too. So it seems something has to be done additionally to set the I/O Priority to the `High` level.

But what?

The tool from [(3)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iopriority/) uses `OpenProcess` from `kernel32.dll` and sets the parameter `dsDesiredAccess` to `ALL_ACCESS`. I tried that one but had no success when calling `NTSetInformationProcess` with a value of `3`.

Thanks in advance!